# calculating sinuosity of each road segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, road, curvature

I want to calculate the sinuocity of each road segment of a vector shapefile which contains roads. I have downloaded the python script from [enter link description here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=00e708a448b74810a0e805c4a97f9d46)

but I don't know what to do after that. I open the python console from Geoprocessing->Python and dragged the file into it but nothing occured. What should I do to run this script and how can I choose the roads file which I want to process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used the tool you downlaoded, but you can use the following calculation to calculate sinuosity.  Open the Attribute Table of the Road feature class, right click the column heading of the Double field you want to hold the Sinuosity value and choose Field Calculator... from the context menu:

[image: Field Calculator...]

Select the Python option at the top of the Field Calculator dialog and paste the code below into the expression:

```
!Shape.Length! / (math.sqrt(math.pow((float( !Shape.FirstPoint.X!) - float( !Shape.LastPoint.X!)), 2) + math.pow((float( !Shape.FirstPoint.Y!) - float( !Shape.LastPoint.Y!)), 2)))
```

[image: Sinuosity Calculation]

Press the OK button and it will calculate the sinuosity value.  A value of 1 is for a straight line, This assumes you are using a Projected Coordinate System where the length and coordinates are in the same unit type (meters, feet, etc.)

The sinuosity values will range from 1 (a straight line) to infinity or error (a closed circle or loop).

Here are what some other values can represent:

A quarter circle (90 degree arc) = 1.11072

Two equal straight lines forming a 90 degree angle = 1.41421

A half circle (180 degree arc) = 1.57096

A 3/4 circle (270 degree arc) = 3.33216

5/6th of a circle (300 degree arc) = 5.23598

Comment: error 999999. The popup window writes "There was a failure during processing, chech the Geoprocessing Results winow for details". The field is not nullable.

Comment: I just ran it on my data, and it ran fine.  I have no closed loops in my roads.  Do you have closed loops in yours?  You probably have some bad features with Null geometry.  They would have zero length (sort on length and look for 0). Run the Repair Geometry tool on your data to get rid of those features.

Comment: I have run the geometry repair. After that I tried to calculate the sinuocity according to your guidelines but the same problem occured.

Comment: Select just one feature which you know is basically a straight line and calculate the sinuosity value just for it.  Does that throw the error or do you get a value calculated?  I just reran the calculation from the code I posted as a test and I have verified that it works (with good geometry and no closed loop roads).

Comment: Are all of your roads single part polyline features?  Please run the Multipart to Singlepart tool on it to verify that no lines are multipart lines.  Multipart lines can have strange start and end positions since although paths may appear to follow a straightforward path they can actually have their line directions scrambled at each self-intersection and gap.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, some road segments which have closed paths have null values. For example the road of a circle square has null value.

Comment: A closed road segment should be null, since its sinuosity cannot really be measured.  Sinuosity in that case is always infinite, since you are dividing the line length by a distance of 0 between the two end points.  So Null is a more meaningful value than some arbitrary outrageously large number that attempts to reach infinity.  Anyway, you really cannot tell anything about the shape of a closed path from a sinuosity value, since it could be a straight line that doubles back on itself, a circle, an oval, a square, a triangle, etc.  It is a special case and Null is the appropriate output.

Answer (score 0):

Open ArcGIS (author says it requires Arc 10.1).
On the Standard Toolbar, select/click on the ArcToolbox button (ArcToolbox icon has little red toolbox on it).

[image]

When the ArcToolbox Dialog window opens, right-click in it and select "Add Toolbox". Browse to where you extracted the Sinuosity.pyt file, click "Open".
This adds the toolbox to your ArcGIS environment.

[image]

Comment: I have run the script  but the sinuocity of the road segments is smaller than one which is not acceptable. Have you run the script without facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sinuosity solution for QGIS field calculator.

```
to_real( $length )  / sqrt( ( ( to_real( $x_at( 0 ) )  - to_real( $x_at( -1 ) ) ) ^2 ) + ( ( to_real( $y_at( 0 ) )  - to_real( $y_at( -1) ) )^2 ) )
```